# jQuery code to concat the id for searching

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to execute some operations on the row controls which I have clicked, all my code is working fine when `txtitemDesc` and `txtitemAmnt` are `1` but when I try to concate `txtitemdesc` and `txtitemamnt` with `rowindex` nothing happens as shown in the code

```
 $("document").ready(function () {
             $("[id$=tblorder]").find('tr').click(function () {
                var rowindex = $(this).index() ;
                 if ($(event.target).is(":checkbox") && $(event.target).is(":checked")) {
                     $("[id$=txtItemDesc]" + rowindex).css('display', 'inline');
                     $("[id$=txtItemAmnt]" + rowindex).css('display', 'inline');
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     $("[id$=txtItemDesc]" + rowindex).css('display', 'none');
                     $("[id$=txtItemAmnt]" + rowindex).css('display', 'none');

                 };           
             });
         });
     </script>
```

I tried the following however the alert value is `NaN`

```
$("document").ready(function () {
             $("[id$=tblorder]").find('tr').click(function () {
                var rowindex = $(this).index() ;
                if ($(event.target).is(":checkbox") && $(event.target).is(":checked")) {
                    var totalId1 = $("[id$=txtItemDesc]").ID + rowindex;
                    var totalId2 = $("[id$=txtItemAmnt]").id + rowindex;
                    alert(totalId1);
                    alert(totalId2);
                     $(totalId1).css('display', 'inline');
                     $(totalId2).css('display', 'inline');
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    $(totalId1).css('display', 'none');
                    $(totalId2).css('display', 'none');
                 };           
             });
         });
```

the html page is

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mstr-homepage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frm-civilwork.aspx.cs" Inherits="frm_civilwork" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">    

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $("[id$=txtdate]").datepicker({
                 showOn: 'button',
                 buttonImageOnly: true,
                 buttonImage: 'images/calender.png',
                 dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
             });

             $("[class$=hiddentextbox]").css('display', 'none');

             $("[id$=tblorder] tr").not(':first').hover(
                 function () {
                     $(this).css("background", "blue");
                 }, function () {
                     $(this).css("background", "");
                 });
         });



         $("document").ready(function () {
             $("[id$=tblorder]").find('tr').click(function () {
                var rowindex = $(this).index() ;
                 if ($(event.target).is(":checkbox") && $(event.target).is(":checked")) {
                     $("[id$=txtItemDesc]" + rowindex).css('display', 'inline');
                     $("[id$=txtItemAmnt]" + rowindex).css('display', 'inline');
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     $("[id$=txtItemDesc]" + rowindex).css('display', 'none');
                     $("[id$=txtItemAmnt]" + rowindex).css('display', 'none');

                 };           
             });
         });
     </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

          <table id="tblorder" align="center" class="auto-style3" border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style9">
                             <asp:Label ID="label11" runat="server" Text="Order Number : "></asp:Label>
                             <asp:Label ID="lblorderno" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>

                        </td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter item description"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="auto-style8"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Amount"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="1">
                        <td class="auto-style12">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCoat" Text="Coat" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style13">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc1" class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="381px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style14"> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt1"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="2">
                        <td class="auto-style5">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShirt" Text="Shirt" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style6">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc2"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="381px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style15"> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt2"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="3">
                        <td class="auto-style5">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPant" Text="Pant" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style6">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc3"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="381px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style15"> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt3"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="4">
                        <td class="auto-style5">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chksherwani" Text="Serwani" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style6">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc4"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="381px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style15"> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt4"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="5">
                        <td class="auto-style5">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkmodijacket" Text="Modijacket" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style6">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemDesc5"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="381px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style15"> 
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemAmnt5"  class="hiddentextbox" runat="server" Width="106px"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style16">
                            </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbltotalamnt" runat="server" Text="Total amount:"></asp:Label>
                        </td>

                        <td class="auto-style18">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbldisplaytotal" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style9"></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">

                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Amount Paid"></asp:Label>
                        </td>


                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtamntpaid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style9">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="description(*optional)"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtdescription" runat="server" Width="300px" style="margin-left: 0px"></asp:TextBox><no br />
                           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Balance" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                       <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblbalance" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style9"></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="select delevery date"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                       <td class="auto-style8">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="92px" OnClick="btnsave_Click" />
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    </table>
     </table>     
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: start with `$(document).` and problem area is `$("[id$=txtItemDesc]").ID` Can you share HTML?

Comment: what is the control id for given textbox ?

Comment: @hdkhardik the id of the 1st textbox is txtItemDesc1 and 2nd textbox is txtItemAmnt1 of the first row and on each new row it becomes txtItemDesc2 and txtItemAmnt2 and so on..